# Changing UIVIEW's transformation/rotation/scale WITHOUT animation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I need to change the size of my images according to their distance from the center of the screen. If an image is closer to the middle, it should be given a scale of 1, and the further it is from the center, the nearer it's scale is to zero by some function.

Since the user is panning the screen, I need a way to change the images (UIViews) scale, but since this is not a very classic animation where I know a how to define an animation sequence exactly - mostly because of timing issues (due to system performance, I don't know how long the animation will last), I am going to need to simply change the scale in one step (no timed animations).
This way every frame the functiion gets called when panning, all images should update easily.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could directly apply a `CGAffineTransform` to your `UIImageView`. i,e:

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
imageView.transform = trans;
```

Of course you can change your values, and or use other `CGAffineTransform`'s, this should get you on your way though.

Hope it helps !